# What's the largest value supported by the math/big package in golang?

Tags: go, biginteger

I'm reading the documentation to the math/big package here:

https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#pkg-constants

I am trying to understand how large a number is too big for math.big, and this looked like a constant I could interrogate.

I see on my machine:

```
fmt.Println(math.MaxUint32)

4294967295
```

How does this relate to the largest integer possible on my machine, for the purpose of calculation?  What are the units of this number?  Is this bytes, or decimal places or something other than the number itself?

Comment: `MaxUint32` is exactly what it's called---the maximum unsigned integer of 32 bits. It's 2^32-1, because that's the biggest number you can represent in 32 bits of binary; the number in binary is just thirty-two 1s repeated: `11111111111111111111111111111111`

Comment: Is this correctly the max supported by the math/big library, corresponding to the newInt() value?  Is a larger one possible through the library or otherwise?

Comment: No it isn't.  In fact, the limit for that library will depend (in part) on how much memory you have.

Comment: No, that is not at all the max. According to the package description: "Package big implements *arbitrary-precision arithmetic*", which means you can essentially use as big of numbers as you like, though you may have to specify max sizes, precision, etc. If you're not familiar with floating point arithmetic, I highly suggest looking up David Goldberg's famous paper "What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic." It's a great read and extremely informative, and should help you understand how the size of the exponents and precision affect your computations.

Comment: Thank you.  My interest in this library is in integers, not floats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[bignum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) libraries usually store big numbers as a sequence of digits (e.g. in [base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) 2<sup>64</sup>). Their limitation is related to the memory available. So the largest number you could represent is tied to the limitation of your virtual address space. You can safely assume that a number even as large as 10<sup>10000</sup> is representable in bignum. Of course, a [googolplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googolplex) is not representable as a bignum (because it has more bits than the number of particles in the universe).

Another limitation is the complexity of arithmetic operations. But there exist very efficient bignum algorithms.

FWIW, the [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/) (a C library for bignums) can deal with numbers as long as there is memory for them. However, it is rumored than when `malloc` fails, GMPlib is aborting.

I don't know what happens inside Go bignums when a number is too big to be representable (and that limit varies from one machine to the next and could be different from one run to the next). For example, Go's [Int.Mul](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Mul) gives a product whose size is the sum of the size of the arguments, and the "out of memory" error is undocumented (but obviously *can* happen).

When using bignums, prefer iterative algorithms to recursive ones. For example, a naive recursive factorial might overflow the call stack with large enough bignums, so you want to code it iteratively.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you have a sample program I could run to see what that max would be empirically, based on memory available and other limitations you mention?

Comment: No. And I don't know how the Go library does that. In practice, you should not care.

Comment: But in practice, I do!  :)  I am working with large factorials, and get stackoverflow errors for obviously super large numbers.  I can probably do repeated trials to test where that is, shooting algorithm above and below, but it takes some time to time out, and will be time intensive to interrogate the bounds. Algo kind of like this: https://play.golang.org/p/feacvk4P4O

Comment: Your stackoverflow is not tied to the bignum limitation, but to recursion depth. Replace your factorial function with one computing factorial in a loop

Comment: Thanks.  Used the built-in MulRange function:
https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.MulRange  Looks better already:
https://play.golang.org/p/44DEMsI5cB5